# Change column values based on index of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with values, which refer to the index of another Dataframe. If I have two dataframes such as:

| index | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | hello |
| 1 | 0 | bye |
| 2 | 1 | bye |
| 3 | 2 | ready |
| 4 | 3 | hello |

| index | value |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | V |
| 1 | W |
| 2 | X |
| 3 | Y |
| 4 | Z |

I need to replace values in A by value in Table 2 based on index. Result must be:

| index | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | W | hello |
| 1 | V | bye |
| 2 | W | bye |
| 3 | X | ready |
| 4 | Y | hello |

Any help, please?

Thank you!

Comment: You can do this using the [join](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) method

Comment: Use `merge`, left on A, right on value. Or `map`, reshaping df2 as Series.

Comment: Hi Ben, join joins by index, but I need to join only one matrix by index, the other matrix is by the column A... Or is therr a way to do join like this?

Comment: Merge looks good to me. I'll give it a try. Thank you.